# Can I change the password of the domain account which I used to create the failover cluster?

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, windows-server-2019, availability-groups

Can I change the password of the domain account which I used to create the failover cluster? Will it affect the cluster at all?
I have also created the Always On availability groups using that domain account, will it be affected?

Regards.

Comment: Were you able to change the password?

Answer (score 1):

You should use SQL Server Configuration Manager to make that kind of change. The [Changing the Accounts Used by the Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver16#changing-the-accounts-used-by-the-services) section of the doc says:

> Always use SQL Server tools such as SQL Server Configuration Manager
> to change the account used by the SQL Server or SQL Server Agent
> services, or to change the password for the account.
>
> [...]
>
> As an additional benefit, passwords changed using SQL Server
> Configuration Manager, SMO, or WMI take affect immediately without
> restarting the service.

In addition to that, the [SCM Services - Change the Password of the Accounts Used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/scm-services-change-the-password-of-the-accounts-used?view=sql-server-ver16) doc says:

> However, in a clustered environment, after changing the password on
> the active node by using SQL Server Configuration Manager, you must
> change the password on the passive node by using the Service Control
> Manager.

See [Using SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/scm-services-change-the-password-of-the-accounts-used?view=sql-server-ver16#SSMSProcedure) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I change the password of the domain account which I used to create the failover cluster?

Yes, the account that creates a WSFC or an FCI isn't the same as the accounts that run them. WSFC runs as a local account and FCI is whatever account you chose. From the question, it's hard to understand if you mean WSFC, FCI, or both.

> Will it affect the cluster at all?

No.

> I have also created the Always On availability groups using that domain account, will it be affected?

Again, hard to tell if you mean the service account running SQL Server that uses an AG or the account used to run the T-SQL commands. If it's the account used to run SQL Server, if it's an FCI use SSCM, if it's a local install for an AG, use SSCM, if it's just the account used to execute the T-SQL then it doesn't matter as this changes nothing.